# Managing npm package installation for non-web developers

Tags: c++, node.js, gruntjs, npm, gulp

I work on a project where I am the only front-end developer amongst a team of C++ developers. When we build our release variant, I want the C++ developers to run the web build process (npm install, grunt/gulp build which does concat/minification/etc...). In order for that to happen, they have to npm install all the devDependencies.

Is there a way to allow them to quickly install the necessary npm modules without having to re-download them ever time npm install is called? Or make the npm install only go through installation once?

npm link doesn't work since that links to the web application and not the node modules that the web application depends upon.

tar.gz would be possible but that means updating the tar.gz every time a node module gets updated.

Curious what development process others suggest for tacking working in a mixed language environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout node_modules to your git or whatever version control you're using, so they won't be downloaded every time.

Yes, someone will have to update modules once in a while, but some people (including npm itself) do just that.

You can also put a caching proxy server (i.e. sinopia) to download packages from, so downloading would be a bit faster.